# Maven PluginManagement in modules

Tags: maven

I stumbled over a maven project with one parent P, that has modules A and B. In this project the modules A and B include a PluginManagement section? Now i wonder: Does this make sense? What could be the intent of this?

matthias.

Comment: out of interest, does it still work when you remove the pluginManagement tag from around the plugins in the child modules?

Answer (score 1):

The PluginManagement sections are placed so that child-elements may all use the same plugins and versions. The children still have to reference the plugins but may omit the plugin version for instance.

I don't think using PluginManagement in modules A and B makes much sense unless its creator planned to extend this and then decided otherwise. It should be replaced by

```
<plugins>
    <!-- your modules -->
<plugins>
```

Comment: Agree, a `pluginManagement` section would make much more sense in project P than either of the child modules.